# How can I see which VLAN a virtual network interface is assigned to

Tags: networking

After I created a new virtual interface like this:

```
ip link add link eth0 name eth0.100 type vlan id 100
```

How can I afterwards verify that a virtual interface is configured for that VLAN?
Neither

```
ip link show eth0.100
```

nor

```
ip a s
```

seems to show any VLAN information.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

found the following solution:

```
cat /proc/net/vlan/eth0.2011 
eth0.2011 VID: 2011 REORDER_HDR: 1 dev->priv_flags: 1 total frames received 1129 total bytes received 55318 Broadcast/Multicast Rcvd 0

total frames transmitted            8
total bytes transmitted          648

Device: eth0 INGRESS priority mappings: 0:0 1:0 2:0 3:0 4:0 5:0 6:0 7:0 
EGRESS priority mappings:
```

Answer (score 17):

Just spotted this question while looking for something else...

You're nearly there.... what you need to use is `-d` to reveal detailed information about a link that you can then `grep` out the VLAN info:

```
$ ip -d link show dev eth0.100 | grep 'vlan protocol'
vlan protocol 802.1Q id 5 <REORDER_HDR>
```

Comment: This should be marked as a solution :)